# Build a REST WebService with GAE using OAuth

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, oauth

I'm about to build a community platform from scratch. We are going to create the WebServices first and the community might have some third party components, so having solid WebServices is a good idea anyway.

Since the service is stateless we need authentication for every single call. Is it a good idea to implement the OAuth protocol for our service provider to perform this task although we are the only consumer right now?

By the way: We will deliver a mobile application before a website is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of OAuth is to allow other websites (consumers) to get access to your data (you are the provider). Since you are the only consumer of your data, there is no need to implement OAuth at this stage of development.

Be lean, build something fast and put it in front of users/testers. Only at this point you will discover real bugs and get a feedback on the service so that you can improve it and steer the development in the right direction.

**Note:** OAuth as [provided by App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview.html#OAuth_and_App_Engine) (second paragraph) only supports users with  Google Accounts (even if OpenID is used).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I will decouple as much as possible having OAuth for later implementation in mind.

Comment: Wrong, OAuth is widely used today to only authenticate (i.e. who you are), without really accessing any of your data.
For example, Google recommends to use OAuth2.0 to authenticate. You just don't request any scopes besides `id` and probably `email`.
And it's the only way to properly authenticate Android users.

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka: OAuth was defined as an authorisation standard not an authentication standard. Sure, in real life consumers use OAuth to authenticate only, but that was not what OAuth was designed for. Also, OAuth does not define authentication, so every OAuth provider implements authentication in their own way, making integration a pain.

Comment: Right. But as I said, currently OAuth is de-facto used to only authenticate by big market players. Twitter API, for example, even calls OAuth as _authentication protocol_, although it's wrong.

Comment: By the way, the most recent authentication protocol, "OpenID Connect" is built _on top_ of OAuth2.0. As they say, it "allows to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server". And it's now the recommended way to authenticate your users on Android. Android accounts don't need to be GMail, you can as well set up your own Authorization Server.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I created the REST WS in a authentication agnostic way: jersey methods accept everything, then there are several filters in order to validate the requests.
I used OpenId authentication for the web part, OAuth and BASIC AUTHENTICATION (with SSL) for API.

Probably it is not needed to create everything from the beginning, but remember to de-couple as much as possible your REST endpoint from the authentication: you will have a great benefit when you want to release APIs.

Last "philosophical" thing: OAuth is not totally stateless, in fact you have a temporary token that authenticates a user and it is similar to a session in the browser!